# How to update cart item when user adds a product to cart via web-view?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android and I have created a simple app where in the top navigation menu is in android native code and the remaining site is in web-view.

Now on the main menu,there is a button for cart and wishlist items. This menu items should have a number on top of it displaying the number of items in cart and wishlist.

So the problem is that when user adds a product to cart via web-view form, it is not immediately reflecting on the native menu. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: not immediately reflecting or not reflecting?

Comment: It is not reflecting actually, because both are in different platform. Actually, I am running a background webservice every 15 seconds to get the total items in cart and wishlist and updating on the cart. However, this approach doesn't looks too scalable to me. Hence I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

When the user adds a product to the cart, you should invoke an Android method from your JavaScript code that updates your counter (supposedly a `TextView`).

You should be able to do something like this in your `Activity`:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void updateCounter(int count) {
    yourTextView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
}
```

Register your `Activity` as a JavaScript interface:

```
// you could do this in onCreate()
yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
```

And then, you can invoke `updateCounter()` from your JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // ...

    // call this function whenever/wherever you would like to update your counter
    function updateCounter(count) {
        Android.updateCounter(count);
    }
</script>
```

Check out [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) on binding JavaScript code to Android code.